# Libgdx Texture is rotated 90 when created from file

Tags: libgdx

When i create a texture with :

```
Texture t = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("image.png"));
```

the texture "t" is rotated 90 ??? why ?

thanks for reading.

Comment: try using Texture t = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("image.png"),false);

Comment: This doesn't happen. I think you are talking about rendering it in a 3d box made with modelbuilder or something (then, it happens :P) correct me if I'm wrong. If thats the case, you must create each side yourself to fix this issue.

Comment: Show the code that binds the texture to an Mesh or Sprite and then renders that object.  Simply loading the texture does not show that it is "rotated".